# C# PropertyInfo

Tags: c#

I can get the PropertyValues like

```
Type mytype=typeof(TextBox);

foreach(PropertyInfo myinfo in mytype.GetProperties())
{
ListBox1.Items.Add(myinfo.Name);
}
```

But Some Properties have child How Can I Find child property of I property?

(Sample Devexpress LookUpEdit component DataSource,DisplayMember e.t.c properties under the Properties)Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do the same loop (recursively) for the PropertyInfo.PropertyType.GetProperties

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PropertyType` property to find the type of the property, then in the same way you examine the properties of the `TextBox`, you can examine these sub-properties.

```
Type mytype=typeof(TextBox);
foreach(PropertyInfo myinfo in mytype.GetProperties())
{
    ListBox1.Items.Add(myinfo.Name);
    if(myinfo.Name == "Parent")
    {    
        PropertyInfo subProperty = typeof(Control).GetProperty("Name")
        if(subProperty != null)
            // Do some more stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to access the PropertyType property of the myinfo object and then get the child properties using GetProperties() from there.

```
foreach(PropertyInfo myinfo in mytype.GetProperties())
{ 
    ListBox1.Items.Add(myinfo.Name);
    foreach(PropertyInfo mychildren in myinfo.PropertyType.GetProperties())
    {
       //do whatever with them
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make a recursive call to a method that take the property and return propertyinfo

Answer (score 1):

You want to grab the type of the property info, then Grab the properties assocciated with that type.

ex:

```
        PropertyInfo info = GetType().GetProperties()[0];
        Type inner = info.GetType();
        inner.GetProperties();
```

EDIT:
I originally said info.GetType() without actually making sure that was right, I apologize. As long as you know what you are expecting then you shouldn't need recursion for anything

something more simple should work fine:

```
PropertyInfo[] infos = typeof(SomeClass).GetProperties();
//Find the Property you are looking for
PropertyInfo propertyWithMoreProperties = ....

PropertyInfo[] moreInfos = propertyWidthMoreProperties.PropertyType.GetProperties();
```

Comment: in order to understand recursion, one must first understand recursion. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can Call

```
 myInfo.PropertyType().GetProperties();
```

To Get All of the Properties